# How should I fix baseball size gaps in early 1900s exterior foundation blocks and crumbling mortar?

Tags: foundation, exterior

I got the paint off and found significant gaps and crumbling mortar. I have about 300 sq feet of block to tackle. What’s up in good condition is in very solid. What isn’t has been damaged by poorly placed or maintained gutters etc. over time.

I have never done any work like this so don’t know what the best materials are to use. I’ll prime and repaint after it’s done. (The many layers of original paint have been removed.)

Comment: Please revise to provide more detail about the wall. Photos would be dandy. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: drypack mortar is the way to go

Comment: Blocks as in cinder blocks? Or do you mean chunks of concrete? No field stones?