# How should I repair baseball-size gaps in early 1900’s era foundation blocks and crumbling mortar?

Tags: exterior, masonry

I have about 300 sq feet of block to tackle. What’s up in good condition is in very solid. What isn’t has been damaged by poorly placed or maintained gutters etc over time.

I have never done any work like this so don’t know what the best materials are to use. I’ll prime and repaint after it’s done. (The many layers of original paint have been removed.)

Ty

Comment: A pic of what issue you have would help.  What makes you believe that gutter issues are to blame?

Comment: If you believe that you have gutter issues and would like advice on fixing those, please feel free to ask a whole new question about it.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. Update the [original one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/276132/how-should-i-fix-baseball-size-gaps-in-early-1900s-exterior-foundation-blocks-an). I've moved some of this post there for you, but it needs clarity.